# Configuring Proxy on 12.04 without gedit installed

Tags: command-line, proxy

New to Linux and the command line, so go easy on me please. I've installed 12.04 and at point of install didn't add the proxy in. I now realise that was a mistake and rather than reload the OS I'd rather know how to do it. I've loaded the Command Line OS, not the GUI version, so after I've logged in,

**How do I add/configure the proxy settings?**

I tried this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

(as I was then going to do: `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxy_server:proxy_port";`)

but was told I need to install gedit first 
So when I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

I get:

```
E: unable to locate package gedit
```

is this because it cannot get to the Web to find it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You do need internet to install stuff in Ubuntu (*via the repositories*). Try `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf` instead. Nano is an easy to use, pre-installed command line text editor - `ctrl-o` to save, `ctrl-x` to exit.

Comment: Hi Mike Thanks for that I have added the changes to the apt.conf file via nano managed to save it ( I think) When I did ctrl & O - it says file name to save I just pressed enter - it says [wrote 2 lines]

do i have to "execute" anything - or has the above actually added the proxy settings?

Comment: It should have added the settings - no need to execute anything. Just close the file with `ctrl-x`.